# Python package with external_modules

Tags: python, setuptools

I have root dir with following structure:

```
.
|-- myproject
|   |-- a
|   |   |-- foo.c
|   |   |-- foo.h
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- b
|   |   |-- bar.c
|   |   |-- bar.h
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- c
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- qwe.py
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- setup.py
```

I want to import the external modules as:

```
from myproject import a
from myproject import b
```

or:

```
import myproject.a
```

And the question is how the ....

My setup.py is like:

```
from setuptools import *

setup(
name                = 'myproject',
.
.
.
ext_package         = 'myproject',
ext_modules         = [Extension("myproject.a", ["myproject/a/foo.c"])]
```

All my **init**.py are empty.
When:
   python setup.py install

The package is installed but cannot refer to a, b and c.

Any idea how to do that?

==========================

Actually i can refer to foo and bar, but cannot see or use any method....???

Comment: Is there a a reason you aren't adding `bar.c`, or was it omitted only in this example?   Also, take a look at `find_packages`, which will automatically find all packages for you.  [Basic use is given here](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#basic-use).

Comment: Also, add backticks around `__init__.py` in your question, because double underscores bolds the text between them.

Comment: What exception gets thrown when you try import a, b, c? just `import myproject` is fine and you can access `myproject.a` etc.. correct?

Comment: You don't need `ext_package` option, since you already specify full extension names. Other than that, your setup seems correct.

Comment: Well this is only example.
But when i try to use mypackage.a.somemethod() it says that there is no such method.... Maybe there is some extra requirement for the extension module?